# How to use some apply function to solve what requires two for-loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a matrix, named "mat", and a smaller matrix, named "center".

```
temp = c(1.8421,5.6586,6.3526,2.904,3.232,4.6076,4.8,3.2909,4.6122,4.9399)
mat = matrix(temp, ncol=2)
       [,1]   [,2]
[1,] 1.8421 4.6076
[2,] 5.6586 4.8000
[3,] 6.3526 3.2909
[4,] 2.9040 4.6122
[5,] 3.2320 4.9399

center = matrix(c(3, 6, 3, 2), ncol=2)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    3
[2,]    6    2
```

I need to compute the distance between each row of mat with every row of center. For example, the distance of mat[1,] and center[1,] can be computed as

```
diff = mat[1,]-center[1,]
t(diff)%*%diff
        [,1]
[1,] 3.92511
```

Similarly, I can find the distance of mat[1,] and center[2,]

```
diff = mat[1,]-center[2,]
t(diff)%*%diff
         [,1]
[1,] 24.08771
```

Repeat this process for each row of mat, I will end up with

```
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  3.925110 24.087710
[2,] 10.308154  7.956554
[3,] 11.324550  1.790750
[4,]  2.608405 16.408805
[5,]  3.817036 16.304836
```

I know how to implement it with for-loops. I was really hoping someone could tell me how to do it with some kind of an apply() function, maybe mapply() I guess.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
apply(center, 1, function(x) colSums((x - t(mat)) ^ 2))
#           [,1]      [,2]
# [1,]  3.925110 24.087710
# [2,] 10.308154  7.956554
# [3,] 11.324550  1.790750
# [4,]  2.608405 16.408805
# [5,]  3.817036 16.304836
```

Comment: Note that this is very similar to mine and it also only loops over center, not mat. This massively speeds things up over looping over mat.

Comment: @John, good point about removing unchanging computations from loop.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the `apply` for expressiveness of code that's one thing but it's still looping, just different syntax. This can be done without any loops, or with a very small one across `center` instead of `mat`. I'd just transpose first because it's wise to get into the habit of getting as much as possible out of the apply statement. (The BrodieG answer is pretty much identical in function.) These are working because R will automatically recycle the smaller vector along the matrix and do it much faster than `apply` or `for`.

```
tm <- t(mat)
apply(center, 1, function(m){
    colSums((tm - m)^2) })
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `dist` and then extract the relevant submatrix:

```
ix <- 1:nrow(mat)
as.matrix( dist( rbind(mat, center) )^2 )[ix, -ix]

          6         7
# 1  3.925110 24.087710
# 2 10.308154  7.956554
# 3 11.324550  1.790750
# 4  2.608405 16.408805
# 5  3.817036 16.304836
```

*REVISION:* simplified slightly.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve it

```
t(apply(mat,1,function(row){
  d1<-sum((row-center[1,])^2)
  d2<-sum((row-center[2,])^2)
  return(c(d1,d2))
}))
```

Result:

```
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  3.925110 24.087710
[2,] 10.308154  7.956554
[3,] 11.324550  1.790750
[4,]  2.608405 16.408805
[5,]  3.817036 16.304836
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You had the right one before. You need to transpose the matrix for the recycling of the math to work correctly, and then take colSums of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `outer` as well

```
d <- function(i, j) sum((mat[i, ] - center[j, ])^2) 
outer(1:nrow(mat), 1:nrow(center), Vectorize(d))
```